# Stop sql query from updating all columns in for each loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

A lot of questions has already been asked concerning this issue. I've gone through some solutions given on stackoverflow but none of them seems to work. I have a form with foreach loop and I'm trying to submit **"the selected form"** with its unique value and then run a SQL query with the value.

The problem is, the name attribute of the text area being submitted. At first the query would only update the last column in the loop. Then I tried a different approach. For example, changing the name attribute to "someattribute[ ]".

Now **all selected columns** in the query are being updated.

**form.php**

```
 <?php
  ...................
  foreach($stmt as $obj){

      $id = $obj['id'];
      $likes = $obj['like1'];


      echo '<form action="" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="lkcv[]" value="'.$id.'">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="like" value="">';
      echo '<input type="image" src="images/like.png" id="lksub" width="15" 
  value="som" height="15" style="float:right;position:relative;margin-
  right:290px;"/><div class="ld">'.$likes.'</div>';
      echo '</form>’;
     }
  ?>
```

**query.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['like'])){

     $com_id = $_POST['lkcv'];

     for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($com_id);$i++){
         # query into db table to know current voting score 
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT like1 FROM comment WHERE id = '$com_id[$i]'");

         # increase or dicrease voting score
         if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

               $like = ++$data['like1'];

               # update new voting score
               $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE comment SET like1 = '{$like}' WHERE id = '$com_id[$i]'");

    }
        }
  }
    ?>
```

**query.php [RESOLVED]**

```
  <?php
    if( isset( $_POST['lkcv'] ) && is_array( $_POST['lkcv'] ) )
    {
      $idArray = array();
      foreach( $_POST['lkcv'] as $value )
  {
    $idArray[] = intval( $value );
   }

   $db->query( "UPDATE comment SET like1 = like1 + 1 WHERE id IN (".implode( 
   ',', $idArray ).")" );
      }
         ?>
```

**NOTE:** i will be updating my query to use PDO prepared statements as soon as i get this working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So whats the actual problem over here

Comment: @Uchiha, the column "like1" is updated for all rows in the comment table. i want only the row with id say "1" to be updated.

Comment: can you please provide output for result query:

echo "UPDATE comment SET like1 = '{$like}' WHERE id = '$com_id[$i]'"

Comment: @Andriy, all +1 is added to the previous value in the "like1" column. so the result is value+1, each time the button is clicked.

Comment: @chris94 As you said name attribute as array[] in hidden field, you have to check in post value whether it is array or not. Then you have to retrieve it through foreach of $_POST['lkcv'].  For example,                 <?php
if(isset($_POST['lkcv'])){
  if (is_array($_POST['lkcv'])) {
    foreach($_POST['lkcv'] as $value){
      echo $value;
    }
  } else {
    $value = $_POST['lkcv'];
    echo $value;
  }
}
?>

Comment: @chris94 additionally, one more question, why you need to use select and update to just increase the like by 1? why not use like this, UPDATE comment SET like1  = like1  + 1 where id = '$com_id[$i]';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this in one query like this:

```
<?php

if( isset( $_POST['lkcv'] ) && is_array( $_POST['lkcv'] ) )
{
    $idArray = array();

    foreach( $_POST['lkcv'] as $value )
    {
        $idArray[] = intval( $value );
    }

    $db->query( "UPDATE comment SET like1 = like + 1 WHERE id IN (".implode( ',', $idArray ).")" );
}
```

Comment: you made a little mistake, like is a reserved keyword in mysql, thats why i used like1. you didnt use like1 + 1. Thanks for your help, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

How many times is this query looping? If every table row is being added to the 'lkcv' array then every row is going to be modified because the FOR loop is being told to loop for each member of the 'lkcv' array.

So if your table has 50 rows and all 50 rows are being passed into the array then each of those 50 rows will be affected.

You can also optimise your code by incrementing the 'like1' field in the UPDATE statement like so...

`UPDATE comment SET like1 = like1 + 1 WHERE id = '$com_id[$i]'`

OR

`UPDATE comment SET like1 = like1 + 1 WHERE id = '$com_id'`

If you want to execute it just once as I'm assuming.

Comment: yes this is the case as it loops 4 times which is the same amount of rows i have in the table. how do i fix this?

Comment: How many times is it supposed to loop? Or is it just supposed to execute once? If the latter then post the id without array brackets and remove the loop so that the query executes just once.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use select and update just to increase the like by 1? why not use directly in mysql? It reduce the code complexity. Try this like below and check the values. If still problem exists, then debug by print_r, echo and exit.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['lkcv']) && isset($_POST['like'])){
  if (is_array($_POST['lkcv'])) {
    foreach($_POST['lkcv'] as $value){
               $query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE comment SET like1  = like1 + 1 where id = '$value'");
    }
  } 
}
?>
```

Hint: Don't use sizeof(). Use count() Instead. refer this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php).

Comment: the value in "$value" is correct, but it doesn't update in my table.

Comment: @chris94  just use where id = '$value'

Comment: the button doesnt work using the "if(isset($_POST['lkcv']) && isset($_POST['like']))" statement.

Comment: @chris94 You didn't show any button in form. you passed lkcv and like both through hidden. So it must be available in POST after this form submit.